# How to target an element in nav bar and change it position using Vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to change the position of my element that has "Shoes" at it data- in the navbar and put in the first position, change the color and add a border-bottom to it using only vanilla javascript
Please find the code bellow
Thank you for your help

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="women" data-niveau="women">
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="shirt" data-niveau="shirt">
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="shoes" data-niveau="shoes">
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="Hat" data-niveau="Hat">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have three data-*="shoes", do you want to put all three of those before data-*="shirt" and "women" ?

Comment: Thank you for your help Rahul, I just edited the code, i would like to put "shoes" in the first position using vanilla javascript

Comment: why do you want to use JS? This can be done soley with CSS (Flexbox + flexoreder or css-grid with grid-area).

Answer (score 2):

```js
let shouesEl= document.querySelector('[data-niveau="shoes"]').parentElement
//get element
let shoues = shouesEl.outerHTML
// save it
shouesEl.innerHTML=""
// remove it
document.querySelector('.main-nav').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", shoues);
//add it
console.log(shoues)
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="women" data-niveau="women">women</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="shirt" data-niveau="shirt">shirt</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="shoes" data-niveau="shoes">shoes</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="Hat" data-niveau="Hat">Hat</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ikik but when I run the code on the console it didn't work

Comment: @OuailTayarth Np, but it didn't work is not help at all, be specific, did you get any errors, also why are you even running in console? It is done how I wrote it and it is working like you see in example fiddle in this post. Maybe something is different on your end? Check the `querySelectorors`, `console.log(shouesEl)` and `console.log(document.querySelector('.main-nav'))` to see if you are getting right elements. Debugging 1on1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want styles from CSS file then You can use flexbox via JavaScript

```js
    const x  = document.querySelector(".main-nav");
    const y = document.querySelector("a[data-before='shoes']");
    x.style.display="flex",
    x.style.flexDirection = "column",
    /*
    for inline menu 
    x.style.flexDirection = "row",
    */
    y.parentElement.style.order=-1;
```

```html
 <div class="main-nav">
        <div class="mobile-menu">
          <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="women" data-niveau="women">
              Women
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
          <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="shirt" data-niveau="shirt">
            Shirt  </a>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
          <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="shoes" data-niveau="shoes">Shoes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
          <a class="js-mm-link" data-before="Hat" data-niveau="Hat">Hat</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for you help it works so well